# Image on canvas is shrunk after clicking

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

I drew the image on the canvas and it gets scaled after I click on the image while the size of the canvas is not changed.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = './assets/images/A4.png';
    this.image.onload = () => {
        const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
        canvas.width = this.image.width = 794;
        canvas.height = this.image.height = 1123;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height);
        this.imageWidth = this.image.width;
        this.imageHeight = this.image.height;
    }
```

How to make the image drawn on the canvas not shrink after clicking on the image?

Comment: There is nothing here that would indicate _anything_ should happen on click. There are no listeners for that event, so it's probably not related to the code you posted...

Comment: This question has really low effort. Please, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask specially the "minimal, reproducible example".